# ¿Como habilitar una celda de un datagridview?

Tags: c#

consulta, tengo un datagrid con un boton de editar, quiero que al darle click me habilite ciertas celdas no todas, cómo podría hacerlo?

Mi código hasta el momento:

```
 if (datagridview1.CurrentRow != null)
                    datagridview1.CurrentRow.ReadOnly = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes habilitar/deshabilitar la edición de celdas individuales cambiando el valor de la propiedad `ReadOnly` de las celdas:

```
datagridview1[numColumna, numFila].ReadOnly = false;
```